# How to preserve date when transferring videos from iPhone to Windows?

Tags: windows-10, video, iphone, photos, ios

I experience the problem that when transferring videos from my iPhone to my Windows PC, that the videos are saved with the date of the transfer and not the date when the videos were taken. This leads a false chronological order and to many duplicates.

I have this problem in Windows 10 using Photo app and also have it in Windows 7.

Comment: Which date? Does the metadata for the video report that the Date Taken is now updated to the date the file was moved, or is it just the Date Updated? Please look at the File > Properties > Details and let us know whether the Date Taken field is actually changed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue was that the HEVC codec support was not installed. In this case Windows cannot read the metadata and uses the date of the transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent iOS videos use per default the HEVC codec. One needs to install the `HEVC Video Extensions` from the Microsoft store. After restarting the photos app the videos are transferred with the correct date.